# iOS: How to handle recurrent update of current user position

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation, ios6

actually I have two questions:

1) What tutorial would you guys suggest in order to implement geolocation tracking in iOS? I found this one http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/ which seems to be pretty good but since it's been written over two years ago I don't know if it by chance uses some deprecated APIs.

2) Let's suppose I've the answer to the first question: how would you guys implement the recurrent update of current user position? Is it possible to run a thread in background which updates the user position every n minutes? Is there a better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good tutorial how to start working with Core Location from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

Answering your second question: Your class should support CLLocationManagerDelegate. When user location changes next method will be called and you can implement everything you need inside it:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
  didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {...}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at it :-)